# Sitecore User Group - Budapest #6

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

**About the event:**

**SITECORE SYMPOSIUM RECAP!**

The next Hungarian Sitecore User Group has been announced! There will be 3 topics:

- What's new in Sitecore 9.1 - Tamas Varga (@Sitecore)
- SXA 1.8 and Sitecore Forms / Marketing Automation in Sitecore 9.1 - Peter Procházka (@Accenture)
- Sitecore JavaScript Services - Tamas Tarnok (@AllWin Informatika)

Free discussions, sandwich and drink after the presentations.

**When (UTC):** Tuesday, November 20, 2018 6:00 PM

**Where:** ALLWIN Informatika, Bartók Béla út 9., Budapest

**[RSVP to this Event](https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-Budapest/events/255823565/)**

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins in 7 hours